# Pass a command line argument to Ant in Hudson

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, build-automation, hudson

I'm trying to pass a -lib argument to ant as part of an automated build using Hudson but can't see a way to do this. I could add the relevant libraries to the ant/lib folder but that would then mean the same version of the library necessarily being shared by all builds on that machine.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Hudson job configuration you can specify ant arguments such as -lib in the Targets field. See the help message that opens when you click the ? next to the Targets field.

Comment: doh, must have been asleep when I was looking over the gui there. thanks.